# How do I create overlays like Poliigon.com ones?

Tags: texturing, materials

I've seen Poliigon.com has these things called overlays where you basically have a smudge or something and you can put it over the material of your object. I want to make some myself since they don't have many options. Here's an example of an overlay.
How would I do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add scratches?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82472/how-to-add-scratches) and [Add scratches to a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles) and [Adding surface scratches](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32166/adding-surface-scratches)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/how-to-make-dirty-looking-object/33054#33054 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93747/adding-smudges-fingerprints-to-a-glass-material

Comment: @cegaton with this you create an image and put it through a normal map and it's done. Not like that. I want to make the image.

Comment: Use any image editing app (krita, photoshop, etc)

Comment: Here you have tutorial on fingerprints: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1SYY0dcCCw also I think this question is unrelated to Blender itself and it's best suited for Graphic Design Stack Exchange.